# TPageControl HighDPI bug

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I would like to modify applications to support HighDPI. I found a problem with TPageControl. When I add to form TPageControl, set align to alTop and on new page I add TEdit with anchors akLeft and akRight then when I change text stretch to 150% and run test application, Edit is bigger then page (in design are edits same).

I'm using Delphi 10.1.2 Berlin and Win10 x64. It's a VCL bug? Is there a fix?

Btw: When I run test project with text stretch 100% and change stretch to 150% then size of edits is OK.

[image: in design are edits same]

Comment: Seems like this one: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14750

Comment: I tried remove override `procedure TPageControl.ChangeScale(M, D: Integer; isDpiChange: Boolean);` but it doesn't work (like recommended fix from RSP-14750). And when TEdit have no akRight anchor then scaling works good.

Comment: Problem is in the `TWinControl.ArrangeControl(...` - [RSP-14023](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14023). There is no working workaround.

Comment: Still a problem in Tokyo 10.2.2 even though RSP-14750 is closed and marked as resolved in Tokyo 20.2

Comment: Placing a TPanel on each TTabsheet, plus moving all controls from the tabsheet to the panel works for me most of the time. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53101899/4110077